# Showing a div onmouseover for table row, and setting text and URL dynamically using row attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a pricing comparison table, and wanted to display more information on each option in a different way.

When a user hovers their mouse over a row, I want the row to show more information on that feature. I now have this working using jQuery and a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#row').mouseover(function() {
        var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        var bottomWidth = $(this).css('width');
        var bottomHeight = $(this).css('height');
        var rowPos = $(this).position();
        bottomTop = rowPos.top;
        bottomLeft = rowPos.left;
        $divOverlay.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: bottomTop,
            left: bottomLeft,
            width: bottomWidth,
            height: bottomHeight
        });
        $divOverlay.text($(this).closest('tr').attr('desc'));
        $divOverlay.delay('100').fadeIn();
        $(this).closest('tr').css({ opacity: 0.01 });

    });
    $('#divOverlay').mouseleave(function() {
        var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        $('#row').css({ opacity: 1 });
        $divOverlay.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

My problem now lies in that in some cases I want to include a link to a video, or another page (that opens in a new tab) - to provide the user with more information if needed. But the way I have this working, the link isn't rendered as html but shown as text instead. Would anyone know how else I could do this?

Full functional example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rMXAp/1/

Another idea I had was setting an onclick for the div, where the href is taken from the "desc_link" attribute (see non-header row in jsfiddle example), but I'm not sure yet on how I can set this with jQuery.

I think it was somthing similar to the following that I tried:

```
$divOverlay.setAttribute('onclick',$(this).closest('tr').attr('desc_link'));
```

Suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .html instead of .text - should do the trick :)

Comment: would putting html tags inside an element's attribute not cause trouble? It doesn't seem to on the fiddle, but I can't work out why not :-$

Comment: So $divOverlay is a dom node, .html() inserts it's parameter as html inside that node.  For example if you had the html: "<div id="test"></div>" $('#test').html('<p>Test</p>'); would output "<div id="test"><p>Test</p></div>"

Comment: Why would it if it's unused out of the box? I'd be interested to know too if it would! And thanks @palacealex, that worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, $divOverlay is a dom node because the OP has used the jQuery $ function to define it as such, var x= $('#divOverlay') would return the exact same thing